# GitHub Pages not updating post

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am currently a very beginner in Jekyll (and also Ruby) and I'm trying the GitHub Pages blog thing at GitHub. Here's the Pages : http://nobodykid.github.io/ and the repo https://github.com/nobodykid/nobodykid.github.io

I've installed Ruby and Jekyll successfully. I've also installed `GitHub-pages` Gem as instructed in https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll

When I tried `Jekyll serve` for the first time to see it locally. I got this error

> `cannot load such file -- kramdown`

When I tried `bundle exec Jekyll serve` instead, the site generated successfully. But with this message :

```
Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes
gem 'wdm', '>=0.1.0 if Gem.win_platform?
```

when I tried to make a new post and publish everything into my repo, only the first sample post by Jekyll that showed. The post that I created didn't show even though I can see it generated with `bundle exec Jekyll serve` locally.

Did I do something wrong somewhere? Thank you for any of your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a time issue - your post date was 3-9 but you did it yesterday which was 3-8 (at least where I am!).

Try doing a commit (of anything) and seeing if it shows now. Remember that the site only builds when you make a commit - so even if the problem was the date, the fact that today is 3-9 won't mean that the post magically shows up - unless it regenerates.

Comment: I thought the `date` variable was just to show dates on the post, but also impact on when the post going to show up. Thank you